# Capture output of a command that get stuck

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, subshell, pcregrep

I am trying to use regex for capturing some text pattern in an ouput of a command and create an array `list_mqs`. The problem is that this previous command get stuck and never terminates. So, when I use a `pipeline | egrep`, never starts the `egrep` command because the other routine did not finish.

The patterns that I am trying to capture are:
`MQ_1A`, `MQ_F5`,`MQ_H7`.

```bash
[user@host] list_mqs=($(command_never_ends | egrep -io "MQ_*"))
```

Is there any way that I can redirect the output of the previous commands even it never ends(or maybe set a counter and if reached exit), and pass those content to be analyzed by the `egrep` routine?

Comment: What do you mean by  `command_never_ends`? Is it literally? Because if this one never ends then the array `list_mqs` should not be necessary. Or you are saying `command_never_ends` because this one gets stuck and never pipe the output to `egrep`?

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe a command/application and this one doesn't show any output it should be due to the `buffer`.

You have two solution (I guess there are more) to can pipe and get an output:

**Solution 1:** Using `unbuffer`

```bash
unbuffer command_never_ends | egrep -io "MQ_*"
#Or if the 'command_never_ends' does really finish:
list_mqs=("$(unbuffer command_never_ends | egrep -io "MQ_*")")
```

**Solution 2:** Using `named pipes`

```bash
#Create the named pipe
mkfifo pipe1
#Redirecting 'command_never_ends' output (stdout,stderr) to named pipe
command_never_ends &> pipe1
```

When you use this: `command_never_ends &> pipe1` the program will not be started until the named pipe **pipe1** has been read. So now you will have to do something like this:

```bash
#Reading line per line the output of 'command_never_ends'
while read -r line; do 
   egrep -io "MQ_*" <<< "$line"
done < pipe0
```

You can see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/719457/414186) about named pipes using a Java application to send data to a pipe.

**Note**
I tried using `stdbuf` command but it seems doesn't work. I know that `stdbuf` and `unbuffer` work in  different ways. If someone knows how can achieve this using `stdbuf` it should be useful for me too.